# How to get the address of a static const property?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, directx

I am calling the following function from DirectX:

```
d3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &ibd, &isrd, &Player::indexbuffer);
```

The indexbuffer is declared like so:

```
static const ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> indexbuffer;
```

The compiler throws:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'HRESULT ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(const D3D11_BUFFER_DESC *,const D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA *,ID3D11Buffer **)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'const Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>' to 'ID3D11Buffer **'
```

How do I go about doing something like this? I only need one constant buffer variable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501(v=vs.85).aspx

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "StructVertex.h"
#include "SquareVertices.h"
#include "WICTextureLoader.h"

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace DirectX;
//using namespace DirectX;

class Player : public SquareVertices
{
public:
    Player( ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice );
    ~Player();

    void Initialize();
    void Update();

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float rotation;
    float velocity;

    static const ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexbuffer;
    static const ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> indexbuffer;
    static const ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> texture;
private:
    const ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice;
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "Player.h"

//const VertexPositionColor vertices[ ];

Player::Player( ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice )
:
    x( 0.0f ),
    y( 0.0f ),
    rotation( 0.0f ),
    velocity( 0.05f ),
    d3dDevice( d3dDevice )
{}

Player::~Player( )
{
}

void Player::Initialize( )
{
    // Create vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd = { 0 };
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( VERTEX )* ARRAYSIZE( Player::vertices );
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA srd = { Player::vertices, 0, 0 };

    d3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &srd, Player::vertexbuffer ); // doesn't work

    // Create the index buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd = { 0 };
    ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof( short )* ARRAYSIZE( Player::indices ); // doesn't work      ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA isrd = { Player::indices, 0, 0 };

    d3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &ibd, &isrd, Player::indexbuffer ); // doesn't work    
    // Load the texture
    CreateWICTextureFromFile( d3dDevice.Get( ), nullptr, L"Wood.png", nullptr, Player::texture, 0 ); // doesn't work    }

void Player::Update()
{
    if( Keyboard::up )
        y += velocity;
    if( Keyboard::down )
        y -= velocity;
    if( Keyboard::left )
        x -= velocity;
    if( Keyboard::right )
        x += velocity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
&Player::indexbuffer
```

is in fact the correct way to get the address of the static member object.

As your error message explains, the problem is that it has the wrong type for the `CreateBuffer` function, which requires a pointer of type `ID3D11Buffer **`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to what will suffer if I do not use the ComPtr? Doesn't it like keep a count of objects or something?

Comment: Like any good smart pointer, `ComPtr` overrides the `&` operator to return the address of the internal pointer it is holding on ot. Thus, `ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>::operator&()` returns an `ID3D11Buffer**`. That is not the cause of the error. The real cause is that `indexbuffer` is declared as `const`. You need to get rid of that to allow `CreateBuffer()` to alter the contents of `indexbuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ComPtr` is fine, as it overrides the `&` operator to return the address of the internal pointer it is holding on to.

However, `indexbuffer` is declared as `const`, but `CreateBuffer()` expects a non-const pointer.  It updates the pointer to point at the new buffer object being returned.  Calling `&` on a const `ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>` instance will return a const `ID3D11Buffer**` pointer, which is not what `CreateBuffer()` is expecting.

Remove the `const`. Calling `&` on a non-const `ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>` will return a non-const `ID3D11Buffer**`, which is what `CreateBuffer()` is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

#### Design

Ask yourself these simple questions:

1. Why would you want your buffers to be static?
2. Why would you want your buffers to be const?

---

#### `Static`?

In C++ we try to avoid `static` variables, as they introduce many problems: global state, sharing and ownership, initialization order, lifetime, thread-safety, etc. Have you really good reasons for this in your `Player` class? Neither `xyz`, nor `rotation` and `velocity` are `static`. So why `static` buffers?

---

#### `Const`?

All "changing" methods requires objects passed to be non-const.

Think about it: `CreateBuffer()` must mutate internal state of buffer to initialize it: assign fields, send buffer's data to videocard, etc. But it cannot, because it's `const`. When you would like to `UpdateSubresource()` it will fail also. Same with texture. How would you load data into read-only object?

So what purpose of `const`ness here?  If you want D3D11 resources to be immutable, just declare `D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE` flag on initialization.

---

Hope it helps.